# Symetrically encrypting a string of arbitrary length with a big integer in python

Tags: python, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I am writing a client and a server with some encryption involved. I've written a diffie-hellman implementation, and the client and the server has now agreed on a secret integer of roughly 2048 bits.

How can I best use this integer to encrypt and decrypt a string of arbitrary length? Said string can vary from only a few characters to being up 2048 bits? Ideally, I would want to be able to encrypt larger strings as well, but for now 2048 is enough. The string is alphanumeric, but I would later prefer to allow for binary data as well. I presume that I will need to encode it into something else anyway?

While the cryptography doesn't have to be that secure, as I have another layer of security, it does have to be able to withstand decryption efforts to a reasonable degree. I have looked into Caesar ciphers and other ROT ciphers, but they strike me as simple to crack.

**The actual question:** Is there a module I can `import` that allows me to somewhat securely encrypt/decrypt the string symmetrically by providing a big integer? Or is there a suitable cipher that I can implement from scratch?

Comment: To me it sounds like you are just converting cleartext to ciphertext using a key, and then decrypting that ciphertext with the same key once it reaches the server. 

There isn't anything complex about doing that, just reverse the function you have on the client side, and add it to the server. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @ChrisS You are very much correct. I am mostly stuck on which cipher to use and/or whether there's a module that can do this for me, or if I should roll my own.

Comment: well you've mentioned that you have your own implementation of diffie hellman, so I wouldn't be sure if there is a library out of the box that can help you with that.

Comment: well, the DH implementation is just for the client and the server to arrive on the Big Integer together without having to worry that much eavesdropping. The issue at hand is how to scramble the traffic from now on, and it boils down to just symmetrically encrypting and decrypting a string using an integer.

Comment: Hmm okay. So initially you asked about encrypting/decrypting the string using the integer, but now you are asking how do you encrypt the traffic which sends the encrypted string to the server? Sorry - I'm a little confused on what exactly you are having trouble with. Why not just use public and private key + some transport protocol (like HTTPS) which encrypts the traffic in transit?

Comment: Ah, I see the ambiguity. I'm already on top of the transmission/reception part. The exact issue at hand is that is that I need to start passing strings that are encrypted, and it is this part where I need some input. Choosing cipher to scramble the string, etc.

Comment: There aren't a whole lot of details here. You should probably be looking at [IES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme). I like the [cryptography.io library](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dh/).